# Redirect full URL to another full URL?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to 301 redirect from `https://whatever-12345.de/something.html` to `https://whatever.de/something.html` using a .htaccess file. I could not find a working example and this does not work:

```
redirect 301 https://whatever-12345.de/something.html https://whatever.de/something.html
```

Ideas?

Comment: I guess it does

Comment: Why not simply `Redirect 301 /foo.html http://example.com/foo.html`?

Answer (score 0):

First alternative, redirect a specific page called /sourcepage.html to another URL:

```
Redirect 301 /sourcepage.html http://Exampledomain.com/
```

Second alternative, redirect the whole domain to another URL:

```
Redirect 301 / http://www.Exampledomain.com/
```

And last, redirect one file to another file, locally, in the same domain:

```
Redirect 301 /old/path/oldpage.html http://www.currentdomain.com/new/path/newpage.html
```

**PHP:**

Now, by this method, you need FTP access to edit files in your server as well. We will create a PHP file named old.php. Here’s how this file will look like:

```
<?php
header("Location: http://www.mynewwebsite.com/blog/"); 
?>
```

This way, whenever we access this specific PHP file, the user will be redirected to our destination site.

We can also use a more complete PHP file, specifying that this is a 301 redirect (permanent). In this case, the PHP file would look like:

```
<?php
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"); 
header("Location: http://www.mynewwebsite.com/blog/"); 
?>
```

Comment: Yeah, but as you can see, the last part is something.html on bith URLs ... the only difference is the domain itself.

Comment: Try redirect using PHP or html meta tag

Comment: How would I do it with PHP?

Comment: Check the edited answer for PHP method.